# Copying data from buffer upto next line

Tags: c, memcpy

In my code i have global buffer which receive hex data. This hex data is nothing but compiler output in intel hex format. I want to remove intel Hex headers and CRC bits from data, convert it into binary data, and write to my application flash addres. For this my question is

To convert data from intel hex to binary i have to read one line from buffer at a time and convert it.
For reading one line form buffer i write code as example

```
char str[];        //buffer whitch hold Hex file 
char readBuffer[128];   //buffer to read data
char * pch;
int iTotalShift = 0;
int iShift = 0;
int iSize = 0;
while(iSize < SizeOfBuffer)
{
    pch = strstr (&str[iTotalShift],"\n"); 

    //this \n may change to actual hex value of \n i.e.0x0D0A

    iShift = (pch - &str[iTotalShift]);
    memcpy(&readBuffer[0], &str[iTotalShift], iShift );
    iTotalShift = iTotalShift + (iShift + 2);
    iSize =  iTotalShift;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this using c code please share....

Thanks in advance

Comment: `char str[];` won't hold anything. It's a buffer of size zero.

Comment: `char str[];` that shouldn't even compile.

Comment: sorry for incomplete code...actually str[] is malloc buffer because my hex size is not fix...so i just declare it as str[];

Comment: The line: pch = strstr (&str[iTotalShift],"\n");  does not need changing as the compiler will handle the detail of is '\n' one or two bytes.

Comment: most of the loop can be eliminated by using sscanf function to read the data from the 'str' array, as the scan will stop at the newline.  Therefore, the format string needs to be " %s" (note the space) so it will skip over any white space ( like "\n" before reading/converting the string.

Comment: this line: while(iSize < SizeOfBuffer) could become: while( pch < str+strlen(str) )

Comment: A couple of observations. You don't need to say `&readBuffer[0]` just `readBuffer` will do. Then `while(iSize < SizeOfBuffer)` you should be testing if there is enough buffer space just before `memcpy()` because the `while` test will pass when there is only 1 byte left.